# Expected value of a continuous random variable must be strictly bounded

Tags: probability, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, expected-value

Given a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ and a continuous random variable $X: \Omega \to I$ where $I$ is an interval of $\mathbb{R}$. I'm trying to show that the expected value $$E[X] = \int\limits_{\Omega} X \, dP$$ must be in $I$.

That is seemingly trivial, but I'm struggling with the case where $I = \left\{ x : a < x < b \right\}$ (i.e. without equalities). While $$a \leq \int\limits_{\Omega} X \, dP \leq b$$ is obvious. I still cannot figure out how to prove $$a < \int\limits_{\Omega} X \, dP < b$$.

Comment: $E[b-X] = 0$ if and only if $b-X = 0$ a.s. Similarly for $X-a$

Comment: The $(1,+\infty)$-valued random variable $X$ with PDF
$$
p(x)=\frac 1{2x^{3/2}}
$$
has infinite expectation.

Answer (score 2):

By upwards continuity of measures, there must exist some $c<b$ such that $P(X\leq c)\geq \frac{1}{2}$
Split $\Omega$ into the events $(X\leq c)$ and $(X>c)$ and integtate over each of those seperately. You can bound X by $c$ on one of the integrals and $b$ on the other, so we see:
$$EX\leq P(X\leq c)c+ P(X>c)b\leq\frac{c+b}{2}<b$$

You can use an entirely similar strategy to show that $EX>a$

Comment: I think there is a problem, if $P(X \leq c) \geq \frac{1}{2}$ then $P(X \leq c) \geq \frac{c}{2}$.

Comment: Do you mean $cP(X\leq c)\geq\frac{c}{2}$? Otherwise your claim isn't true in general?
Either way, there is no problem - if P(X\leq c)\geq\frac{1}{2} we see that
$$cP(X\leq c)+bP(X>c)=cP(X\leq c)+b(1-P(X\leq c))=(c-b)cP(X\leq c)+b$$
As $P(X\leq c)\in[\frac{1}{2},1]$ and $c<b$ we see that the expression above has its maximum at $P(X\leq c)=\frac{1}{2}$, and that maximum is exactly $\frac{c+b}{2}$ - so the inequality I claim does indeed hold.

Comment: Thank you, I understood your solution. The idea is to show that there exists $c < b$ (without equality) so that $P(X < c) > 0$. For which we can use the continuity from above: $\lim_{c \ to  b} P(X < c) = P(X < b) = 1$.

Comment: Could you please revise your answer then I will accept it.